# Variable vector size in all class instantiations in c++

Tags: c++, class, vector, size

I'm trying to code a chess game for usage in terminal. A game consists of a Board class, consisting of Piece classes. For each piece I want to determine the allowed moves if no other pieces where on the board and put this in a vector<pair<int,int>> (a1 = 1,1).

You can image that for a Queen you have more allowed moves than for a pawn. Ideally I would like my Piece to have a variable size vector so it is just filled with moves for that specific Piece.

This is my Piece instantiation:

```
class Piece{
 private:
  int row;
  int col;
  // number of moves made by the piece
  int moveCnt;
  // white = 1, black = -1
  int color;
  // 'p', 'n', 'b', 'r', 'q', 'k' 
  char type;
  // permissable moves for the piece
  vector<pair<int,int>> permMoves;
  // allowable moves for the piece, taking the entire board into account (1. Ke2 is not allowed but permissable)
  vector<pair<int,int>> allowedMoves;
```

and then for the allowed permissable moves I do this:

```
void Piece::computePermMoveS(){
vector<pair<int,int>> emptyPermMoves {{0,0}};
  permMoves.swap(emptyPermMoves);
  // PAWN
  if (getType() == 'p'){
    // add move to one row ahead
    pair<int,int> add_pair (getCol(),getRow()+1*getColor());
    permMoves.push_back(add_pair);
    if (getMoveCnt() == 0){
      // add move to two rows ahead
      pair<int,int> add_pair (getCol(),getRow()+2*getColor());
      permMoves.push_back(add_pair);
    }
    cout << "new pawn at " << getCol() << ", " << getRow() << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(permMoves)/sizeof(permMoves[0]); i++){
      cout << permMoves[i].first << ", " << permMoves[i].second << endl;
    }
  }
```

The last printing statement is for debugging purposes. If I compile and run this, I get that each piece (pawn, rook) has three permissible moves (as a pawn, which is first in the loop has -> 0 0, a3, a4).

Could anyone tell me how to fix this? I tried reserving 21 moves (the most possible) with

```
Piece(){
    permMoves.reserve(21);
    allowedMoves.reserve(21);
  }
```

but this is not the solution I want and I don't get this working either. So I would really like to use the original approach of each piece having their unique allowed moves.

Comment: `permMoves.reserve(21);` -- Don't you mean `resize(21)`?

Comment: This approach doesn't work as allowable moves can be contingent on a previous move and on the behaviour of other pieces in previous moves, e.g. en-passant for pawns. Castling is also a consideration: amongst other things you are not allowed to castle through check.

Comment: @Bathsheba I'm aware, this is where allowedMoves comes in. There is permMoves() for any move possible on the board if no other pieces are present. From these permMoves, moves are removed that cannot occur so while a castle is possible in the very first move of the game for the king, it being blocked by the bishop later prevents this in allowedMoves. Perhaps my method is weird though hahaha

Comment: @J.V. But en-passant is a move that *becomes* allowable. Are you saying that a pawn moving diagonally is always going to be an allowed move? which is explicitly eliminated. It's been over 20 years since I wrote my chess program (Z80 machine code) and I'm sure the world has moved on since (!), but I only considered allowed moves in the current context - i.e. with all pieces present.

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<sizeof(permMoves)/sizeof(permMoves[0]); i++)` -- This does not do what you think it does.  This does not give you the number of entries in a vector.  The `std::vector` has a `size()` member function.

Comment: @Bathsheba Yeah, my reason for doing this was that otherwise you would need a lot of spaghetti code to find the allowed moves. I think in the end it does not matter and I might need to change my approach but it seemed intuitive at the time. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie well that actually worked! thank you so much. So why did this not work? I saw it being used a lot...

Comment: Look at the line closely and compute all of the pieces.  What is `sizeof(permMoves);`?  What is `sizeof(permMoves[0])`?.  This could never work correctly, since `sizeof` is a compile-time constant that denotes the number of bytes a data type occupies.  So you could have had 1000 entries in the vector, the number would still be (in your case) 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for (int i=0; i<sizeof(permMoves)/sizeof(permMoves[0]); i++)`

This line is incorrect.  The number of entries in a `std::vector` is given by the `size()` member function:

```
for (size_t i=0; i<permMoves.size(); i++){
  cout << permMoves[i].first << ", " << permMoves[i].second << endl;
}
```

What you are doing is assuming that `std::vector` works the same as an array, but that is not true.

A much easier way to perform the loop is to use a [ranged-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) instead:

```
for (auto& p : permMoves)
    cout << p.first << ", " << p.second << endl;
```

Comment: This did the trick! Now I can actually see what's going wrong using the debugging. Thank you very much.